# Optimizing Finding Results in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

My question is regarding the way Rails handles queries in Rails 2.3.

I am currently looking at some legacy code and wanted to try see if there was a better way to go about this rather than using the collection that the previous programmer used.

As a Rails 3 minded person I think there should be a better way to do this. To me this seems like it would be a costly operation to run, but maybe the Rails way of doing it uses the same method so calling it would only be a convenience

```
def self.entity_assigned(entities)
    return nil if entities.size == 0
    conditions = "#{EntityUser.table_name}.entity_id IN (#{entities.collect{|x| x.id}.join(',')})"
    find :all,
          :include => [:entity_users => :entity],
          :conditions => conditions
  end
```

If someone can let me know if there is a better way to do this or if I should continue with the current way.

Comment: i now know that collect and map have the exact some functionality so a simple optimization there will not change anything. I am just hoping there may be a better rails convention to use